# Fish 3.3.1 shell: how do I negate the results of a string match?

Tags: fish

as above.

basically I want to implement something like

```
if not match then
  do these things
else
  do these other things
fi
```

Thanks

Comment: Why would you not just swap the `do these` blocks ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by match, but if you mean "exactly match", you can use the `string match` builtin with a plain argument.

```
if not string match --quiet -- "some_string" $some_argument
    echo no match
else
    echo match
end
```

To match within a string, you can use a glob in `some_string`, or a regular expression with `string match --regex`.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to `not string match -q -- $pattern $string` (as [mentioned by @Zanchey](/a/689360)), you can also do:

```
if string match -vq -- $pattern $string
  echo no match
else
  echo match
end
```

(`-v` like in `grep`, or `--invert` (like GNU `grep`'s `--invert-match`) to invert the match).

You'll see a difference when matching the pattern against more than one string (like when `$string` above is a list with more than one element) or when matching against no string at all (`$string` is an empty list).

```
if not string match -q -- $pattern $string1 $string2
  echo none of the strings matched
else
  echo at least one the strings matched
end
```

```
if string match -vq -- $pattern $string1 $string2
  echo at least one of the strings did not match
else
  echo all the strings matched
end
```

Comment: I tried something like this but I used "-q -v" and it didn't for me. just tried it again and it worked. thanks